Virtual Desktops with only minimized windows causes video card to disconnect cyclically
WHEN using windows virtual desktops
IF the current a desktop has no windows maximized
THEN the monitors switch off then on, as if they have been unplugged and then plugged back in. This repeats  cyclically, evert 3 seconds.
ALSO if any of my virtual desktops have no windows maximized
AND I am on a virtual desktop that does have a maximized windows
THEN the same behavior happens intermittently (~5 minutes, maybe)
This is about the strangest problem I've ever had.
Windows 11 Version  10.0.22631 Build 22631
AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics

I wasn’t able to reproduce this behavior on either my Windows 10 22H2 system or my Windows 11 24H2 system, which likely means, you have a hardware or driver problem

FYI: I have edited the question.
I cant imagine how this could be a hardware issue.

“WHEN using windows virtual desktops
IF the current a desktop has no windows maximized
THEN the monitors switch off then on, as if they have been unplugged.” - I am unable to cause my monitors to switch off by just using virtual desktops no matter how I interact with them. Do you have a different monitor you can use?

This is occurring when I am using one monitor, or multiple monitors.

As crazy as this being sound, it turns out that this was most likely a bad HDMI cable issue. I do not know how that can be given my symptoms, but there it is. I'm now using a usb-c monitor and waiting for a new HDMI cable. I'll update this if new information invalidates this answer.
